# repeat request after 1 minute using observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I want to load data from 5 API's after every 1 minute to refresh the page.
To send the request and get all the data together I though I will user **Observable.forkJoin** and to repeat it every time i put it inside a setInterval.

Something like below.

```
setInterval(function () {
            console.log("INSIDE SET INTERVAL")
            return Observable.forkJoin(
                self.http.get(url1, { headers: headers, method: 'GET' }).map((res: Response) => res.json()),
                self.http.get(url2, { headers: headers, method: 'GET' }).map((res: Response) => res.json()),
                self.http.get(url3, { headers: headers, method: 'GET' }).map((res: Response) => res.json()),
                self.http.get(url4, { headers: headers, method: 'GET' }).map((res: Response) => res.json()),
                self.http.get(url5, { headers: headers, method: 'GET' }).map((res: Response) => res.json()),
            );   
        }, 60000);
```

But when i try to subscribe to this function it says

> Property 'subscribe' does not exists on type 'void'.

i have implemented the same using `Observable.timer(60000)` but then each request resides in different files and it becomes difficult to track.

is there a better way to  implement it?
Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: You should use Arrow function`()= {}` instead of `function ()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is better way to do the same,

Instead of `setInterval`, You should use `Observable.interval`

```
let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/';

let response = Observable.interval(60000).switchMap(() =>
                    Observable.forkJoin(
                        this.http.get(`${url}1`).map((res: Response) => res.json()),
                        this.http.get(`${url}2`).map((res: Response) => res.json())
                    )   
                );

response.subscribe(([data1, data2]) => {
    // your code
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-interval-forkjoin)** (You can check the console log)

And I think , you can't return value from `setInterval` directly , as you have used in your code , for [more read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882306/return-value-inside-a-setinterval)

Comment: Thank you This is what i was looking for .i could not figure out how to combine timer and forkJoin.

Comment: @ShrutiNair, Glad to know that , happy coding :)